# Databound value of textbox/checkbox is incorrect until textbox/checkbox is validated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

**I have a winforms checkbox that is bound to a property of an Entity Framework entity.**

So for example, I have `bindingSource.DataSource = myDog` with a checkbox bound to the property `IsSleeping`, so that when the user checks the box, `IsSleeping` becomes true, and when the user unchecks the box, `IsSleeping` becomes false.

This works fine.  The problem is that the value of `IsSleeping` is not updated until the checkbox is validated, which only occurs when focus moves *away* from the checkbox to something else.  Thus, if I want something to happen when the box is unchecked:

```
private void IsSleepingCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnDogPropertyChanged(myDog);
    MyAnimalEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

`myDog.IsSleeping` will still be true, until the checkbox's `Validated` is later raised.  Thus, when poor `myNaughtyKitty` *(who is listening to the `DogPropertyChanged` event)* comes to eat out of `myDog`'s food dish thinking `myDog` is sleeping, `myDog` is really just waking up!  **Oh no!**

*Even worse*, `MyAnimalEntities.SaveChanges()` does not see the changes to `myDog` yet, so the value of `IsSleeping` is never saved to the database.  Moving the `.SaveChanges()` call to `IsSleepingCheckbox_Validated` does not solve this problem, because if the checkbox is toggled but then the form is closed without ever moving focus *away* from the checkbox, **the checkbox is never validated** and thus its state is never saved!

I imagine this must be a fairly common problem with databinding and checkboxes/textboxes, and indeed I've found a ton of posts on the subject online, but no one ever seems to have a solution.  **Has anyone been able to find a workaround for this?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the [Binding.DataSourceUpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) property to `OnPropertyChanged` (the default is `OnValidation`), which will cause the data source to be updated when the user clicks the checkbox.  Unfortunately, the `CheckedChanged` event still fires before the data source is updated.

To deal with this, you can handle the [BindingSource.ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged.aspx) event and move your `SaveChanges` code there.

```
bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = myDog;
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", bindingSource, "IsSleeping"));
checkBox1.DataBindings[0].DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;

bindingSource.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(bindingSource_ListChanged);
```

HTH

Comment: You saved my life after hours of searching in google. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is the appropriate way to make this work.
Handle the CheckBox Validated Event

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles Check Box State if Changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void checkBoxBidSummaryItem_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to execute...
        _MyEntity.Save(_businessObject.SelectedBid);
    }
```